# Net Maui - Label IsVisible binding not working?

Tags: binding, maui, .net-8.0

I'm trying to hide a label using the MVVM way, I've created a boolean CanModify property (using Toolkit) but no way to make it work..
My Model

```
    public partial class Service : BaseModel //derived from ObservableObject
    {
        public Service():base()
        {
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ServiceImage> Images = new ObservableCollection<ServiceImage>();

        [ObservableProperty]
        private int _id;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private string _description;

     
        [ObservableProperty]
        private bool _canModify;  // <======
}
```

Viewmodel

```
 public partial class ServiceViewModel : BaseViewModel
 {
     [ObservableProperty]
     private Service? _service;
     
     public void SetService(Service service)
     {
         _service = service;
     }

     public ServiceViewModel():base()
     {
        
     }
 //other stuff (commands)
}
```

SIMPLE TEST

Code behind

```
  ServiceViewModel serviceVM = new();
  Service s = ConnectionClient.Client.GetService(value["serviceid"]); //Works & retrieve data from REST
  s.CanModify = true;
  serviceVM.SetService(s);
  this.BindingContext = serviceVM;
```

Page

```
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:ServiceViewModel x:Name="ViewModel"/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

//other stuff

 <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Service.Images}">
     <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
         <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="2" VerticalItemSpacing="5"/>
     </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
     <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                 // other stuff
                 <Entry Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference ViewModel},Path=Description}" TextColor="White" /> //<== THIS WORKS

                <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" 
                  Text="&#xf044;"
                  FontFamily="fontawesome"
                  TextColor="White"
                  FontSize="20"
                  HorizontalOptions="Center"
                  IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference ViewModel},Path=CanModify}" //<== THIS DOESN'T WORK
                  VerticalOptions="Center" >
               </Label>
              // etc...
```

Notes:

- I use a SfTabbedView
- I've to use the binding reference 'cause I'm a collection view so I reference to main binding
- IsVisibile seems to me always "true"
- model, viewmodel and page are registered with AddTransient
- .Net 8.0 in Visual Studio 2022 (recently updated)

I'm unable to make it works and if possible I prefer to use binding than working on code behind.

Comment: I see two issues.  First, you are setting the BindingContext in both the XAML and the code behind.  Pick one approach, not both.  Second, your CanModify property is on Service,, not the VM so the binding path should be “Service.CanModify”

Comment: Don't know if that matters a lot, but if you're using the CommunityToolkit your private properties should probably start with a lowercase letter (here "canModify" instead of "\_canModify", same goes for your \_service => service into your viewmodel). I don't know if Community Toolkit is able to recognize "\_".

Comment: @Jason thanks for the first advice... the second (sorry) I'm ve missed to write that I copy the value of the property from viewmodel to model (both have a CanModify... a result of all my tests :( )

Comment: @GChapX yes, it works fine (recognize both canX and _canX)